# What VPS should I use for my soon-to-launch Rails app?

Tags: vps, ruby-on-rails

I'm about to launch my first Rails app, but I haven't yet selected who I'm going to use for my VPS.
I'm aware of Linode, Slicehost, and pgrmr as options. Any specific pros and cons about each? What other options should I be aware of?

Comment: Where is your primary target audience located? It makes quite a difference if you target North America and have your server located in Europe for example.

Comment: Do you need a VPS? Could you get away with cloud hosting like Heroku?  Maintaining a VPS massively adds to the amount of work you need to do compared to running in the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only going to be using rails, I've heard good things about Joyent.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.hetzner.de/en/hosting/produkte_rootserver/eq4/

Dedicated server with nice specs, at 49€ a month. This includes 19% VAT, which might not apply to you.

I don't use them myself, but have an acquaintance that's very happy with his server.

Comment: I'm using them for one of my clients and have been fairly happy.  We had a server go down a couple of weeks ago and they hooked up a KVM for us 15 minutes after calling them up.  Rebuilding a server with them isn't as nice as most VPS providers, but it's good to have full access and for the price it's fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using rackspace for vps and im very happy with their service, affordable also IMHO.
For shared host, i'm using railsplayground, not to fast but it quite good considering their pricing and excellent support.

Answer (score 0):

We're taking VPS from [OVH](http://ovh.co.uk) for RoR Apps and happy with it.